# jQuery get list item value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I have a basic html list

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li class="active">Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to get the value of list item which has class of active. So, I can find the item by using...

```
$("ul li.active");
```

But `.val()` is not working on list items. What should I be using instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea.

You should use `.text()` to get text of `li` element.

```
$("ul li.active").text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.text()` instead of `.val()`

> .val() works on input elements (or any element with a value
>   attribute?) and .text() is for the innerHTML (similar to .html() ).

you can look at following jsbin.

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/yodaxuwuda/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

Use .data().value instead of .val() when working with li element.

```
  <li data-value="20">twenty</li>
```